# What mushroom species is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Found in garden ,Brisbane Australia at base of trees and amongst plants in open ground
[image]

Comment: you need a decent mushroom book m8. flipping through the pages of a well photographed book always leads to a close ID, and good ones have spore drawings too.

Comment: Could you describe the substrate they were growing on? For instance were there wood chips under the plants, or were the fungi growing on soil? Did you get any photos of the stipe (stem, if any) and a clear shot of the pattern of the gills?

Comment: These look like they fall under the description of 'gilled fungi with lateral or no stipe' (there looks to be a lateral stipe on at least some of the fruiting bodies), so it should be in https://www.fncv.org.au/wp-content/themes/field-naturalist/publications/fungi_in_australia/fia-8-pg-lateral-stipe.pdf. Crepidotus crocophyllus *sounds* like a close match, but the pictures don't seem to agree as closely...